# Using Python Boto3 AWS Lambda, S3 Key LastModified returns in two types for two different ways

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

The LastModified of a given key returns in two different formats.

If I store in a variable or directly print, it gives me this format:

```
2019-04-17 11:14:11+00:00
```

And

If I try to store it as a value in a dict, and then print it, it shows in this format:

```
{'redshift_data_source/grid/load.csv': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 17, 11, 14, 11, tzinfo=tzlocal())}
```

Why such a difference in formats?

Secondly, my purpose is to store the LastModified in a file and check everyday if the LastModified of the file has changed or not. How can I do it without uploading .zip of extra libraries?

I want something like this (where a should come from the file I am storing the metadata and b should be the latest file's metadata read:

```
a = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 17, 11, 14, 11, tzinfo=tzlocal()) # yesterday
b = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 18, 05, 53, 19, tzinfo=tzlocal()) # today

print(a < b) # True
```

Comment: If you are checking every day, then there is no need to actually store the previous value for `LastModified`. Rather, just check if the `LastModified` date is in the previous 24 hours (being careful with timezones).

Comment: To be honest, I wrote that scenario for easier understanding of the person who'd be answering. Actually my scenario is, anytime (whenever a person uploads a new file in source system it will be pulled to S3 and immediately the Lambda should be triggered for Redshift copy for three tables using a single Lambda function. Since, I don't see an option to selectively run parts of the Lambda code using passing some argument from S3 Events for those files which are updated, I am doing this metadata storage for those files. What do you think, is there a better way to address this?

Comment: I am confused when you say "selectively run parts of the Lambda code". Perhaps if you were to provide full details of what you are trying to do, we can offer a better suggestion. Feel free to create a new question with the details.

Comment: Wrote a fresh question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794233/triggering-aws-lambda-on-arrival-of-new-files-in-aws-s3?noredirect=1#comment98257437_55794233

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using stringification of the value I get from the metadata:

```
str(datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 17, 11, 14, 11, tzinfo=tzlocal()))
```

The above line gave me:

```
2019-04-17 11:14:11+00:00
```

And then, for a comparison I had to strip the last portion, as that is not fitting into any standard date format, so I did:

```
old = datetime.datetime.strptime(tables_dict[objects["Contents"][0]["Key"]][:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

And then do my comparison to go ahead with the logic.